# Determine the number of employees needed in a call center using call times in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Using the picture attached, I would like to determine, in a excel or VBA function, which employee I need to answer that call by using the start and end time of previous calls. [Call log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp0JF.png)

Comment: Based on which logic. What have you tried? Post data as data, not picture please.

Comment: There is a lot missing here. Your title asks for Number of Agents Needed while your question seems to ask Which Employee Needs To Answer. Total needed agents can be calculated based on expected call load in the service interval and an expected Grade of Service. Next Agent routing is usually done based on Most Idle. Two different problems entirely.